# A simple case of converting a class to a pointer of that class

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion

I am getting a compiler error with this section of code. It is saying that there is no suitable conversion from NPC to NPC*.

```
Player::Player(Game* g) {
    target = g->getNPCListItem(0);
}
```

This is what is called in main:

```
int main()
{
    Game* gameRef = new Game();
}
```

This is the constructor of Game:

```
Game::Game() {
    player = new Player(this);
}
```

And finally, here is the code for the target pointer:

```
class Player {
    NPC* target;
}
```

I have a feeling that another part of my code is the problem.

Here is the property:

```
class Game {
    NPC* nPCList[2];
}
```

Here is the intialization:

```
bool Game::initNPCList() {
    nPCList[0] = new NPC("Gregory");
    nPCList[1] = new NPC("Tasha");
    return false;
}
```

And finally, here is the function being called in the line that could be producing a compiler error.

```
NPC& Game::getNPCListItem(int i) {
    return *nPCList[i];
}
```

Let me know if I need to add any more information.

Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CloutGame, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>misc.cpp
1>C:\Zach In A Bear Studios\CloutGame\CloutGame\CloutGame\misc.cpp(66,31): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'NPC' to 'NPC *'
1>C:\Zach In A Bear Studios\CloutGame\CloutGame\CloutGame\misc.cpp(66,28): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>Done building project "CloutGame.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Error list:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0413   no suitable conversion function from "NPC" to "NPC *" exists    CloutGame   C:\Zach In A Bear Studios\CloutGame\CloutGame\CloutGame\misc.cpp    66  
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'NPC' to 'NPC *'   CloutGame   C:\Zach In A Bear Studios\CloutGame\CloutGame\CloutGame\misc.cpp    66
```

Comment: Doesn't you compiler tell you which line *exactly*? Please add that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
NPC& Game::getNPCListItem(int i) {
    return *nPCList[i];
}
```

to

```
NPC* Game::getNPCListItem(int i) {
    return nPCList[i];
}
```